# How Can I control file size of pdf (S, M, L) based on image quality using wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I have to control PDF size based on their image or content quality, how it can be achieved using wkhtmltopdf shell utility tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [help section](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) you can use the `--image-quality <integer>` parameter to control the quality of the images. Replace `<integer>` with a number between 1 and 100 where 100 is the best quality. I would suggest trying 80, sometimes 70 still gives acceptable results but it depends on the image.

Comment: Thanks got your point, but is there any other option to control file size while creating it.